# Cloud Corresponding tool of Max QDA

Tags: cloud, azure-cognitive-services, text-analytics-api

I am working on a project for cloud migration data from on-premise to cloud and we have encountered an advanced text analytics tool called **MaxQDA** , is there any tool available on/compatible with azure for doing advance text analytics , we are looking at azure-text analytics but options are limited  . Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You can get benefit from the [Azure machine learning service/Designer](https://ml.azure.com/),

and Azure cognitive services [Text Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/index).

•   LUIS for conversation released new Machine Teaching technology. LUIS now supports more complex schemas with sub-entities of different types. This enables building more sophisticated models like extracting food orders in drive thru scenarios. Try it out on the [preview website](https://preview.luis.ai).

•   LUIS for documents is powering the Project Cortex experience that enables subject matter experts to build custom models to drive content types and populate columns automatically with meta data extracted from documents. This automated metadata capture capability provides productivity savings and consistent tagging of content to aid in discovery, business process automation, and compliance with security and retention policies.

Comment: I have been trying to find more information about LUIS for documents without success. Do you have any links where I can read more about it?